# A geometric criterion for uniqueness in the Plateau problem?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, minimal-surfaces

Let $\gamma: S^1 \to \partial B \subset \mathbf{R}^3$ be a smooth, simple closed curve in the boundary of the unit ball. Suppose that $\gamma$ intersects every horizontal plane $\Pi_t = \{ z = t\}$ at most twice:
\begin{equation}
\# \gamma(S^1) \cap \Pi_t \leq 2 \quad \text{for all $t$.}
\end{equation}

> Does $\gamma$ bound a unique minimal disk (resp. minimal surface)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no.

Take two parallel circles of unit radius in $z=\pm \epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ small.  Tilt the two circles very slightly toward one another. This satisfies your hypotheses.  There are clearly at least three minimal surfaces with this boundary the tilted flat disks and a stable and unstable annulus (obtained by perturbing the appropriate pieces of a catenoid).

If you want non-uniqueness in the class of disks then form a small bridge between the two closest points on the circle.  This boundary also satisfies your hypotheses.   The  [bridge principle](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01192091) implies there is a stable minimal surfaces with this boundary that should look like the two flat disks joined by a small bridge.  However, it is pretty clear the area minimizing disk is the "ribbon" solution going around the outside.  Hence, you have two distinct minimal disks.

Comment: That's neat, thanks!

Comment: I thought I had seen a criterion like this in the literature, but I must have gotten it mixed up with another 'Rado-like' argument.

Comment: If the boundary is a graph then the Rado argument would imply the surface is also a graph which gives uniqueness in a lot of situations.